# Constant function returns empty (string)?

Tags: web3js, string

I have the following code:

web3

```
    var fromAddr = u.addr;
    var contractAddr = this.addr;
    var abi = this.abi;
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddr);
    console.log(contract.getString(x,y,{from: fromAddr, value: 0, gas: gas}));
```

I have also tried with variations such as

```
    var d = contract.getString.getData(x,y);

    var r = web3.eth.call({ to: contractAddr, data: d });
```

and with encoding the inputs using BigNumbers

```
    var input1 = web3.toBigNumber(-97);
    var input2 = web3.toBigNumber(33);
```

solidity

```
function getString(int x, int y) 
    myModifier(msg.sender) 
    public constant returns (string) 
{        
    return string_bucket[x][y][0];
}
```

when I use Mist to get string_bucket[x][y] it returns correctly. When I use web3, it doesn't. The variable string_bucket is not public, does that matter since getString is public? Also, I've tried updating the ABI - no luck. myModifier is used on other functions that are correctly executed/called.

If someone could add the tags return, string, and constant I'd appreciate that.

**Edit:**

It seemed the modifier was coded incorrectly, I fixed it but still same problem.

Regardless, when I remove the modifier from the function to return a string, it works. It seems most likely that my function to populate the variable the modifier checks might be incorrect. The weird thing is I have tried in Mist (using the same population function) and it works but doesn't from Web3. If I find an update to this later in development will let y'all know. I will be back as removing that modifier is a temporary fix - having it there is critical to the functioning of the DAPP.

Comment: can you provide the code of myModifier?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem with Web3. Truffle returns the string though.